# Make ListView have a filter like Contacts app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm rewriting my old Win 8.1 Phone app into UWP (only mobile) but I can't find anywhere how to make the filter like the Contacts app has:

[image: clicking on header letter]

[image: after clicking the header letter]

This is what I basically have so far, and I have the `Tapped` event tied to the header letter, but is there any finished control or do I **have** to make it all custom?

[image: my app so far]

Gotta say I have mixed feelings about UWP so far, can't believe they didn't provide a simpler way of transferring old Win Phone apps...

Thanks in advance for any help you provide guys!

Comment: check out [UWP Community Toolkit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SemanticZoom` control is definitely what you are looking for. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/semantic-zoom) for more information.

Comment: Yup, this is definitely what I was looking for, can't believe I didn't see it! Thank you so much man!